# database access from asynchronous code in Django-channels

Tags: python, django, database, asynchronous, django-channels

I need some help. I'm using Django-channels and I need for some purpose make several DB calls. Docs not clear for me: https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/databases.html 
So, what one of the following is the right way? 
1. Create/call function for each database access with a decorator. 
2. Make all calls to the database in one function, which wrapped by decorator?

Comment: Improved formatting

Answer (score 2):

You can put multiple calls to the database in one function and wrapped by database_sync_to_async decorator like an example below (a chat room as expected :) )

```
class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):

async def connect(self):
    self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
    print(self.scope['user'].username)

    self.room_group_name = 'chat%s' % self.room_name

    await self.channel_layer.group_add(
        self.room_group_name,
        self.channel_name
    )

    await self.accept()

async def disconnect(self, close_code):

    await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
        self.room_group_name,
        self.channel_name
    )


async def receive(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None):
    text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
    message = text_data_json['message']
    await self.channel_layer.group_send(
        self.room_group_name,
        {
            'type' : 'chat_message',
            'message' : message
        }
    )


async def chat_message(self , event):
    message = event['message']
    sender = self.scope["user"].username
    receiver = self.scope['path'].split('_')[1]
    await self.post_message(sender = sender , receiver = receiver , message = message)
    await self.send(text_data = json.dumps({'message': message})) 

@database_sync_to_async
def post_message(self , sender  , receiver , message):
    sender = User.objects.filter(username = sender)[0]
    receiver = User.objects.filter(username = sender)[0]
    Message.objects.create(sender = sender , receiver = receiver , text = message)
```